# Check how many minutes crossed in a time range

Tags: php, datetime, time

How do I get the amount of worked minutes from a crossed time range?

For example:

```
$begindate = "00:00";
$enddate = "08:00";
if(isSaturday($begindate)){
   //00:00 - 06:00 || 149%
   if(strtotime($begintime) >= strtotime("00:00") and strtotime($begintime) <= strtotime("06:00")){
      $weekend149 = true;
   }
}
```

The code currently sees that the person has worked between the hours but I want to get the specific amount he has worked BETWEEN that time range only.

So if he worked from 03:00 till 08:00 I want to have a separate variable that says 3 hours or 180 minutes.

Comment: Php has a Datetime class with a "diff" function. That should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have two time intervals and are looking for the time span of the overlap. This can be done well with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Date and time should be used for correct calculations. If only a time is specified, the calculation is made for the current date.

```
$startdate1 = "03:00";
$enddate1 = "08:00";
$startdate2 = "00:00";
$enddate2 = "06:00";

$startdate1 = date_create($startdate1);
$enddate1 = date_create($enddate1);
$startdate2 = date_create($startdate2);
$enddate2 = date_create($enddate2);

$startOverlap = max($startdate1,$startdate2);
$endOverlap = min($enddate1,$enddate2);

$diff = $startOverlap < $endOverlap 
  ? $startOverlap->diff($endOverlap)
  : false
;

echo $diff ? $diff->format('%h:%i:%s') : 'no overlap';
```

The output is limited to 24 hours. If the difference can be more than 24 hours, you have to include the days in the format.

You can test different times yourself at https://3v4l.org/Fa1sE.